# How do i creat a program that can stop people from using other programs

Tags: java, windows

Hell fellow programmers, I hope you can help with a problem I have. I gave my self the task to design a program that could be used in schools. This program would have a registration field and a log in field, when a student logged in, they would have a couple of options.They could check the notes they have taken from previous classes, or "go to class". Going to class would be achieved by a teacher generating a code and giving them the code to enter the class. Since I don't want kids messing around during class, I wanted them not to be able to access any other applications once they entered a class. Does anybody have an approach to solving this problem of how i could implement this feature to 'lock kids out' of other applications? Thanks in advance P.S: i was thinking that kids would be able to bring their laptops to school and take notes a that way.
- a newbie programer

Comment: Java is probably not the right language for this. You want low-level access to operating system APIs. Also, I'd just download an existing "kiosk mode" program.

Comment: Would you force people to install this software on their own laptops? What would you do against them installing the software on a VM?

Comment: If you're a "newbie programer", as you would put it, perhaps you should start off with something "newbie"...

Comment: I didn't even notice the last sentence. If you made my kid install this kind of possibly broken possibly insecure program on their laptop, I'd make you eat it. Just have them use school computers only in class.

Comment: @Josh M i just wanted to see if it could be done i wanted to present it to my principal see if we could implement it into the system to make a school a bit more interesting and its also a challenge ;)

Comment: @millimoose I had the idea that the program would only lock people out if it was runnning. In term people could just re-boot their computers if need be. There also could be codes that would override the password that the teacher needs to give and those would be held by admins. But if people re-booted their computers it would show on the teachers screen that , that person is offline(or something like that).

Comment: It's their PC. If you put a kiosk program on it, they would have to have the facility to turn it off, otherwise they could never use it outside of school!

Comment: What school is this, people will want to make sure their kids never go there?

Comment: @TodorPenchev Round peg; square hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locking people out of an environment is very hard. Doubly so in Windows. Even in high schools nowadays you're gonna have to deal with script kiddies which will find ways to outsmart your app.

I once worked in a college and I saw the kids there spending more time playing games than paying attention to classes, so I made a Windows service that would monitor the processes in the machine. I kept a black list with the process names of their favorite games and emulators. If such a process was opened, my service would pick a random amount of time (between 30 and 90 seconds) and start a countdown. At the end of the countdown, it killed the process (the kids usually got the hint after 4 or 5 tries). This was extremely frustrating and infuriating to them, which I found through experimenting to be more effective at getting them to stop with the gaming during class than just simply blocking their games.

So my suggestion is this: you could keep a white list of allowed processes, and close/block any process which is not on the list. Bonus if you have a way for the school staff to add or remove programs from this list.